# Question on Net Present Value, Discount rate, and Opportunity Cost

Tags: investing, discount

I recently viewed a Youtube on Net Present Value (NPV), to gain a better understanding of the concept. Towards the end of the  [video](https://youtu.be/HFFkFMfotT0?t=8m44s) the uploader makes the claim that the project has added value to the firm, above and beyond the 6% that they could have invested elsewhere.

But that doesn't make sense. If you could have invested the original 10,000 elsewhere at 6% per year you would get 10,000 ( 1 +.06)^5 = $13382.26 for a profit of $3328.26.  This is greater than the calculated NPV of $3239 for the project.

I am also confused about how the discount rate is calculated. It seems that once you find a discount rate, it is always better to invest the money elsewhere than to undertake a given project whose cash flow you are discounting.  For example in the problem above it makes more sense to invest the money elsewhere at 6% than to invest it in the project.

Comment: You should include the relevant numbers in your question, rather than asking people to watch a video. What discount rate do they use? What's the nominal profit? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of the 10,000 * (1+0.06)^5 = 13,382.26 does not take into account the time value of money. You wouldn't get that entire profit of $3328.26 today, you get it five years from now. Meaning you need to discount it by (1.06)^5 in the denominator to get the NPV.

[10,000 * (1.06)^5] / (1.06)^5 = exactly 10,000. -10,000 in year 1 + 10,000 in year 5 = exactly 0.

So the correct comparison here is $3239 > 0, not $3328.26.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What does NPV = 0 indicate. Is that what happens if you chose not to do the project and just invest it in a 6% investment , like a 6% cd that you cash in after 5 years? Though 6% seems pretty high.

Comment: Correct. Every year the 6% interest you gain is exactly canceled out by the 6% discount rate, so you're neither better nor worse off.

Comment: Also it looks like the rate of return of the project can be calculated another way. If you add the cash-flows 2500 +4000 + 5000 + 3000 + 1000 = 15,500 , this is larger than the 10,000 * (1+0.06)^5 = 13,382.26. And 10000(1 + .092)^5 = 15,500. So the overall rate of return on the project is 9.2%

Comment: Nope. You can't just simplify like that. Every cash flow needs to be discounted based on when it's paid out.

Comment: @john the 6% interest rate is very high but that's because it's chosen to make the maths interesting and a little bit easier rather than to be realistic. Its the finance version of Vikram buying 14 apples and 21 oranges in school textbooks.

Comment: @SlugFrisco it seems like it depends on the details of where you choose to invest. For example, if I had a bank savings account that offered 6% annually, then I don't really have a negative cash flow at all.  My cash flows for compounded interest are:  [0, 600, 636, 674.16, 714.609, 757.486] for years [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].  If we convert these to PV, then it is [0, 566.037, 566.037, 566.037, 566.037, 566.037]. 
This gives a NPV of 2830.185.  In this scenario, a NPV of 0 is equivalent to getting 0% interest in your savings account. Is this correct?

Comment: Hey @Tom - 3 things re: your example which I'll split up due to char limit:
 
1) If you got a cash flow of $600 at end of Y1, that means you took it out of your bank account and could do whatever you wanted to do with it. This means you start with 10,000 at beginning of Y2, so you get $600, not $636, at end of Y2. And so on for the the other years. 

2) You need to include your initial investment, -10,000 into the account at end of Y0.

3) This isn't an infinite investment, you take the money out and end of year 5, meaning you need to add +10,000 at end of Y5.

Comment: (continued) So really your cash flows are [-10,000, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600+10000]. If you discount this you'll see NPV=0.

NPV=0 means that the cash flows given by this investment are exactly offset by the prevailing interest rates, and this investment would leave you neither better nor worse off by the time it is done.

Comment: Aha. I didn't realize cash flows needed to be stated with respect to the other, non-savings account. I thought it was that we were supposed to measure flows with respect to the savings account...so that the interest counted as positive cash flow while I kept it in the savings account. Ok, so in that case, my cash flows are [-10000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13382.2557] and then it is exactly as you said in your first post. Makes much more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom Exactly. For NPV questions, whether it's a savings account/bond/house/whatever, any investment vehicle can be simplified to a self-contained black box. Money goes in at certain times, money comes out at certain times, and you just discount the flows (whether negative or positive) when they are put in or paid out.